# PushNotificationIOS.getDeliveredNotifications(callback) is not working on device

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-push-notification

I have used below method to identify the count of notifications delivered  in IOS app of react-native.

```
PushNotificationIOS.getDeliveredNotifications(callback);
```

Full Code Snippet:

```
 /*Actions to be taken when notification clicked*/
 clearNotificationDesk = (notification) => {

  PushNotificationIOS.getDeliveredNotifications((deliveredNotifications) => {
  const deliveredNotificationsCount = deliveredNotifications ? deliveredNotifications.length : 0; 
  });
  if (AppState.currentState != 'active' && deliveredNotificationsCount > 0) {
    this.navigate("to some screen");
  }
});
```

}

When I run this on simulator, its gives me proper delivered notifications count, however, when I ran it on device its always giving me 0, even device has delivered more than 1 notification.

Have anyone faced similar kind of issue? Any pointer would be very helpful.